# Using jQuery, find the links that contain a certain string and add a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div><a href="link1">blah</a></div>
<div><a href="link2">blah</a></div>
<div><a href="link3.swf">blah</a></div>
<div><a href="link4">blah</a></div>
<div><a href="link5.swf">blah</a></div>
<div><a href="link6.swf">blah</a></div>
```

Using jQuery I want to retrieve the links that contain the `.swf` extension and add a class to their parent `div` element. Here is my code, which is not working:

```
$('a[href:contains(".swf")]').parent().addClass=('filmtrigger')
```

Can you help me fix this?

Comment: `:contains` only works for the contents inside a tag - the inner text of the tag. You're looking to match the value of an attribute (hint: Aaron provided the answer)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now I want to remove the <a> link, but keeping the text content that is inside it. I need to strip only the <a> tag that wraps it. What do you recommend me to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('a[href$="swf"]').parent().addClass('filmtrigger');
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick! Now I want to remove the <a> link, but keeping the text content that is inside it. I need to strip only the <a> tag that wraps it. What do you recommend me to do?

Comment: Technically, he asked for 'contains,' not 'ends with,' (even though his example was a file name - it could have a query string).  Change the 'href$=' to 'href*=' for the correct answer.